# Multiple cases in T-SQL table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create user defined function, that returns all values from a particular product from stock. It should be like this:

```
 Select * from Task10('PC',100,500)
```

Also all data are in different tables, and i don't know how to do this without IF statement. Another difficulty that user defined functions that returns TABLE need to start with Select. This code segment that doesn't work for me.

```
USE MyDataBase
GO
if OBJECT_ID ('Task10','FN') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION Task10;
GO
Create function Task10 (@type_product VARCHAR(10),@min_price FLOAT, @max_price FLOAT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN(
Select *, case @type_product
when 'PC' then (products.Model = pc_uri.Model AND products.type='PC' AND pc_uri.value>@min_price and pc_uri.value<@max_price)
when 'Laptops' then (products.Model=laptop_uri.Model AND products.type='Laptops' AND laptop_uri.value>@min_price and laptop_uri.value<@max_price)
when 'Printers' then (products.Model=Printers.Model AND products.type='Printers' AND Printers.value>@min_price and Printers.value<@max_price)
from case @type_product
when 'PC' pc_uri,products
when 'Laptops' laptop_uri,products
when 'Printers' Printers,products
)
```

This one works, but doesn't return all attributes, just two.

```
USE MyDataBase
GO
if OBJECT_ID ('Task10','FN') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION Task10;
GO
Create function Task10 (@type_product VARCHAR(10),@min_price FLOAT, @max_price FLOAT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN(
Select distinct product.Model,product.Type from product,laptops,printers,pc_uri
      where (
         (@type_product = 'PC' AND product.Model=pc_uri.Model AND product.Type='PC' AND pc_uri.value>@min_price and pc_uri.value<@max_price)
      OR (@type_product = 'printers' AND product.Model=printers.Model AND product.Type='printers' AND printers.value>@min_price and printers.value<@max_price)
      OR (@type_product = 'Laptop-uri' AND product.Model=laptops.Model AND product.Type='Laptop-uri' AND laptops.pret>@min_price and laptops.value<@max_price)
      )
)
```

Comment: left join should solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. using left join where you get to match everything but let the type of product decide where to get the value.

```
Create function Task10 (@type_product VARCHAR(10),@min_price FLOAT, @max_price FLOAT)
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS RETURN(
    Select products.*, case @type_product
    when 'PC' then pc_uri.value
    when 'Laptops' then laptop_uri.value
    when 'Printers' then Printers.value
      else 0 end price
    from products
      left join pc_uri on pc_uri.Model = products.Model and (pc_uri.value>@min_price and pc_uri.value<@max_price)
      left join laptop_uri on laptop_uri.Model = products.Model AND (laptop_uri.value>@min_price and laptop_uri.value<@max_price)
      left join Printers on Printers.Model = products.Model and (Printers.value>@min_price and Printers.value<@max_price)
```